# Is there a way to pass a value to a hidden field to multiple blocks printed from a template file?

Tags: 7, webforms

The scenario is a template (tpl) file outputting a list of contact forms where each one is unique to a term ID in it section on the page. I need to generate a custom options list per printed Webform block using a tid passed from the section it's in in the template.  So far I don't see any way to do this.

*sample.tpl.php*

```
<?php
   $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'my-block-3581');
   print render($block['content']);
?>
```

The above is printed for each section (node) on the page and I have access to the tid where the Webform block is printed but I can't figure out any way to pass it to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use `drupal_get_form` function to retrieve a form in drupal. this function allows you to send any needed arguments for example you can call it like this:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('SOME_FORM_ID', $argument1);
```

in this case `$argument1` value is passed and can be accessed in `hook_form_SOME_FORM_ID_alter` as follow:

```
if(isset($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]) {
  $form['SOME_ELEMENT']['#default_value'] = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]; //as $arguments1 is passed as first parameter
}
```

now having this in mind, to get a webform using `drupal_get_form` you need this code snippet (better to use hook_preprocess_HOOK to add webform to your render array):

```
$nid = ; //YOUR WEBFORM NODE ID
$node = node_load($nid);
$submission = (object) array();
$enabled = TRUE;
$preview = FALSE;
$webform = drupal_get_form('webform_client_form_' . $nid, $node, $submission, $enabled, $preview, $YOUR_ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENT);
```

and then in your template file you can simply print your $webform:

```
print drupal_render($webform);
```

as I said you can use hook_form_alter to set default value of your hidden element using sent parameter.

Comment: I think that it is useful to say, that it is not a good idea to call `drupal_get_form` in template files. Ideally, OP will need to use one of the preprocess functions in template.php, or pass $webform as a parameter to that template file (if the `theme()` function is called directly, for example from a custom module).

Comment: @JurajNemec and I think that is a good idea to say that it was already mentioned in the answer

Comment: Thank you! One more question. How can I access the argument in the Webform once it's sent via drupal_get_form()? I'd like to populate a hidden field, if possible.

Comment: You can use hook_form_alter and then you can access your argument $form_state['build_info']['args'][4]

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian Well, I wrote my comment because for me it is not clearly stated in you answer. You wrote it as a side note only in the parentheses, so it seems like that there is only a small weight on that expression. But nevermind, I just wanted to help the OP with best practices...